# Bash OpenSSL is not equal to php openssl_encrypt value

Tags: bash, encryption, aes, openssh, encryption-asymmetric

I am trying to reach the same value of encryption in bash  as it is from php , with no success .

Here is my php script

```
$message ='{"coupon_key":"011205358365345679","location_id":"288","device_key":"test_1234"}';

$key = "password";

$iv = base64_decode("dU+AyWweQYhAlGKLaxoS9w==");




    $base64_iv = base64_encode($iv);
    
    $base64_ev = base64_encode($encrypted_value);
 


    $encrypted_value = openssl_encrypt(
        $message,
        'AES-256-CBC',
        $key,
        OPENSSL_RAW_DATA|OPENSSL_NO_PADDING,
        $iv
    );


    $encode = base64_encode($encrypted_value);

//Zi7UcBwqM+gKZC9iZPgF3UHBXLUg1+Age/1+kRIfcstYBgGfYm7N1qCIFnm6jGn4AGQph/Q6hKjR1hYBT0wkJv8c8qFrHHZNUuraMfSRH3s=

   
    $mac = hash_hmac('sha256', $base64_iv . $encode, $key);
    



    echo '{"iv":"'.$base64_iv.'","value":"'.$encode.'","mac":"'.$mac.'"}'."<br>";

    //{"iv":"dU+AyWweQYhAlGKLaxoS9w==","value":"Zi7UcBwqM+gKZC9iZPgF3UHBXLUg1+Age/1+kRIfcstYBgGfYm7N1qCIFnm6jGn4AGQph/Q6hKjR1hYBT0wkJv8c8qFrHHZNUuraMfSRH3s=","mac":"97fb6f4226a917322c7361af1d9b2949ad96691c1fc1a7f1c8379c71ae19f356"}
   
    $retString2 =  base64_encode('{"iv":"'.$base64_iv.'","value":"'.$encode.'","mac":"'.$mac.'"}');
    echo $retString2;
    //eyJpdiI6ImRVK0F5V3dlUVloQWxHS0xheG9TOXc9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiWmk3VWNCd3FNK2dLWkM5aVpQZ0YzVUhCWExVZzErQWdlLzEra1JJZmNzdFlCZ0dmWW03TjFxQ0lGbm02akduNEFHUXBoL1E2aEtqUjFoWUJUMHdrSnY4YzhxRnJISFpOVXVyYU1mU1JIM3M9IiwibWFjIjoiOTdmYjZmNDIyNmE5MTczMjJjNzM2MWFmMWQ5YjI5NDlhZDk2NjkxYzFmYzFhN2YxYzgzNzljNzFhZTE5ZjM1NiJ9
```

and here is my bash version

```
password="password";
passwordhex=$(echo "$password" | xxd  -c 256 -ps) ;

# iv2=$(hexdump -n 16 -e '4/4 "%08X" 1 "\n"' /dev/random) ;

iv=$(printf  'dU+AyWweQYhAlGKLaxoS9w==' | base64 -d )



biv=$(printf "$iv" | base64) ;
hexiv=$(printf  "$iv" | xxd  -c 256 -ps) ;
eString=$(printf '{"coupon_key":"011205358365345678","location_id":"288","device_key":"test_1234"}');
tttw=$(printf "$eString" | openssl aes-256-cbc -e   -nosalt -a -A -K   "$passwordhex"  -iv "$hexiv") ;
echo "$tttw" ;

printf "${biv}${tttw}" |openssl dgst -sha256 -hmac abc -macopt hexkey:"$passwordhex" | sed 's/^.* //';

macopt2=$(printf "${biv}${tttw}" |openssl dgst -sha256 -hmac abc -macopt hexkey:"$passwordhex" | sed 's/^.* //');

echo "$macopt2"

finalString="{'iv':'$biv','value':'$tttw','mac':'$macopt2'}";
echo "$finalString";
sendHash=$(printf "$finalString" | base64 -w 0)
echo "$sendHash"
```

Starting from
tttw=$(echo -n $eString | openssl aes-256-cbc -e   -nosalt -a -A -K   $passwordhex  -iv $hexiv) ;

it goes wrong , because $tttw is returning then

`bKG5quB9/YQUsmlFvDHq2H+AfNGQuDfVztyi0dd5hCY7hLfaACnjD8SWlwqy0yy4hXUZSA2YcTXej/xtMg9vqEpoO6CDw9hk7+tUcYOOV5aOdVBnSLowmEllHt0JfjdE`
instead of `Zi7UcBwqM+gKZC9iZPgF3UHBXLUg1+Age/1+kRIfcstYBgGfYm7N1qCIFnm6jGn4AGQph/Q6hKjR1hYBT0wkJv8c8qFrHHZNUuraMfSRH3s=`

Can anybody maybe see what option is going wrong here?

Note1: I have updated the bash script to use prinf instead of echo -n

Note 2 : Seems on my newer machine I get "hex string is too short, padding with zero bytes to length"  from the line

```
 tttw=$(printf $eString | openssl aes-256-cbc -e   -nosalt -a -A -K   $passwordhex  -iv $hexiv) ;
```

Comment: Paste your script into shellcheck.net.  There are a lot of issues with this script, and it is difficult to pinpoint where this is going wrong.  Also, `echo -n` is not very portable.  `printf` is usually a better option if you are trying to avoid the newline, however, many of these `echo`s are sort of pointless.

Comment: OPENSSL_NO_PADDING is not a valid option for openssl_encrypt (you probably meant OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING). There is so much back and forth here that it's really hard to tell what's going on. Start with a PHP and shell script that uses no variables at all (only string literals), and go backwards from there. Consider using GCM mode if you want to authenticate your ciphertext; GCM has that built-in.

Comment: Dear @Peter both options exist. Seems they are equal.

Comment: @jason which issue do you see. By me it works smoothly, just value is different . And echo's are just so that one can see which value comes out. It's for debugging, and if you would paste it into the  command line it will help you, no?

Comment: On my machine OPENSSL_NO_PADDING has value 3, OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING has value 2. The disjunction with OPENSSL_RAW_DATA *happens* to be the same value (again, on my machine), but it's an incredibly bad idea to rely on coincidence in crypto code. Stick to the docs.

Comment: @Peter I will not use PHP. I just need to migrate it command line , to use it in very different environment. If I had possibility to use PHP , it would not be issue to discuss. Unfortunately i have to figure out how to achieve it on shell side..

Comment: @Peter I have cleaned it up on Shellcheck.net . And I have changed echo -n to printf as per your recommendation.  The result is the same.

Comment: @Peter I have checked right now. Both OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING and OPENSSL_NO_PADDING on my server return the same value . By you it's different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the issue is near the very top:

```
passwordhex=$(echo "$password" | xxd  -c 256 -ps) ;
```

So essentially the output of `echo "$password"` is `password\n`.

Using `echo` like this will append a line feed to the input for `xxd` which I assume you already know since the original script was packed with `echo -n`.  I mentioned in the comments that `printf` is more portable.  The accepted way to use printf with a variable is like this:

```
passwordhex=$(printf '%s' "$password" | xxd  -c 256 -ps) ;
```

The reason for this is that if your variable has a format identifier (like `%s`), it would change the output unexpectedly.  This would have also showed up on shellcheck.

With this one change, here is the output:

```
Zi7UcBwqM+gKZC9iZPgF3UHBXLUg1+Age/1+kRIfcssepjJ8+wUjTDAjPUMkGA+eF9EL284iD5UIzA+REyhMWLWbUJpPltHFk1+lhQyVlUXXVTw0FFV1G+iQfEWhbyg4
484123c33b54e446c61120112955cd15f3592f42e737c9fa24db266cdec954a2
484123c33b54e446c61120112955cd15f3592f42e737c9fa24db266cdec954a2
{'iv':'dU+AyWweQYhAlGKLaxoS9w==','value':'Zi7UcBwqM+gKZC9iZPgF3UHBXLUg1+Age/1+kRIfcssepjJ8+wUjTDAjPUMkGA+eF9EL284iD5UIzA+REyhMWLWbUJpPltHFk1+lhQyVlUXXVTw0FFV1G+iQfEWhbyg4','mac':'484123c33b54e446c61120112955cd15f3592f42e737c9fa24db266cdec954a2'}
eydpdic6J2RVK0F5V3dlUVloQWxHS0xheG9TOXc9PScsJ3ZhbHVlJzonWmk3VWNCd3FNK2dLWkM5aVpQZ0YzVUhCWExVZzErQWdlLzEra1JJZmNzc2Vwako4K3dValREQWpQVU1rR0ErZUY5RUwyODRpRDVVSXpBK1JFeWhNV0xXYlVKcFBsdEhGazErbGhReVZsVVhYVlR3MEZGVjFHK2lRZkVXaGJ5ZzQnLCdtYWMnOic0ODQxMjNjMzNiNTRlNDQ2YzYxMTIwMTEyOTU1Y2QxNWYzNTkyZjQyZTczN2M5ZmEyNGRiMjY2Y2RlYzk1NGEyJ30=
```